# Is it possible to revert the order of letters in a field using MySQL functions for sorting purposes?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, sorting

I am making a reverse dictionary (for example, the word 'Word' is considered in it as 'droW' for ordering and index purposes, 'Letter' becomes 'retteL' an so on). I see quite a clear way: to add an additional field and fill it with the reversed words and then order the table using this field. Of course, I can do it in the supplementary program fetching the value, reversing it ans setting the value in the new field. But I wonder:

1. Is it posssible to fill this additional field by a MySQL query?
2. Can we order the table sorting by varchar fields in a reverse way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. See MySQL's `REVERSE` function - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_reverse
2. AFAIK there is no way to do an index starting from the end of a `VARCHAR`

Comment: Thank you. It quite suits me.